# DataTable Column with Custom Data Type

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, datagridview

I have written my own data type that is then used as the type for a column in a datatable.  I am reading XML data from a file.  After I call the ReadXML(file) method, all the cells have values except for the cells in the columns with my data type.  Is there some operator I need to override so that ReadXML(file) can take the data from the file and make a MyDataType out of it?  Also, when I try to sort the defaultview on this column, I get "Object reference not to an instance of an object."  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create a column using a custom data type.

Assuming that you want a property to be of type Address:

```
var ds = new DataSet();
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(Address));

ds.Tables.Add(table);
```

If you want to be able to serialize your dataset (you cannot serialize a datatable), you have to ensure that your type `Address` is serializable.

There are multiple way to mark as class as serializable. The easiest is to use the `SerializableAttribute`. But I recommand that your `Address` class implements the `IXmlSerializable` interface. It may be a little harder, but you will avoid the versioning problem.